# Problem installing TYPO3 8.7 in Ubuntu, got error while installing

Tags: typo3

I am trying to install TYPO3 8.7, installed using symlinks, but I got following error:

```
Directory / is not writable
Path /var/www/html/exists, but no file underneath it can be created.
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -als /var/www/html` and tell us if you use apache2 or another webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy, it's not an issue with TYPO3. As error showing, your directory has no access to write.

Probably, your project directory is not writable, So TYPO3 unable to write required files. please give the proper permission and make sure your directory is writable.

Use below command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/yourProject
```

Also, another possibility is your local server root(`/var/www/html`) has no access permission. you can take a look too.

Hope this will help you!